# useParams() parameter is not updating, always undefined

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am working on a custom Amazon Connect CCP, implemented with React.
Given the following code, profile_id is always returning undefined.

```
const Dashboard = ({ children }) => {
  const divCCP = useRef(null);  
  const { profile_id } = useParams();

  const handleAccepted = async (contactId, profileId, channelName) => {
    await insertTranscript(contactId, profileId, channelName);
  };

  const init = () => {
    const ccpUrl = "https://xxxxxxxx.connect.aws/connect/ccp-v2";
    const connectRegion = "xx-xxxx-xx";
    window.connect.core.initCCP(divCCP.current, //rest of configuration
    );
    
    window.connect.contact(subscribeToContactEvents);
  };

  function subscribeToContactEvents(contact) {
    
    contact.onAccepted(handleContactAccepted);
    
    async function handleContactAccepted(contact) {
      await handleAccepted(
        contact.contactId,
        profile_id,
        contact.getAttributes().chatframework_Channel.value
      );
    }


  }

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex h-screen">
        <div className="w-3/4 px-10">
          {React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
            child.type === Main
              ? React.cloneElement(child, { profiles, setProfiles })
              : child
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="w-1/4">
          <div className="h-full" ref={divCCP}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried using useEffect with the profile_id parameter, with no luck.
Here is the defined route for the component:

```
<Route
    element={<Dashboard children={<Profile></Profile>}></Dashboard>}
    path={"/profile/:profile_id"}></Route>
```

profile_id is probably not being updated before the function is called, because if another call is received and the page is not refreshed, the profile_id seems to display a value, but I cannot find a way to wait until it is updated, .

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I generally use with useParams() is:

```
const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
   if (params["profile_id"]) {
      // do stuff
   }
}, [params]);
```

You can then set to a variable in `useState()` or if it's a one shot just use inside the `useEffect()`.

In this specific case you could:

```
const [profileId, setProfileId] = useState();
const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
   if (params["profile_id"]) {
      setProfileId(params["profile_id"])
   }
}, [params]);

useEffect(() => {
   if (profileId) {
      init();
   }
}, [profileId]);
```

You'd need to update your init function to use the new profileId constant, or you could skip and pass the profile_id as a parameter to your init() function. Whichever works better.

Comment: The init() function needs to be initiated even if params is undefined. However, the window.connect.contact(subscribeToContactEvents) function always needs to be listening and profileId should be updated inside it.